# make ansible inventory file secure or way to validate it before deployment

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

Can we have any way in which I can verify my ansible inventory file before deployment so that i can be sure that prod host are not listed under the DEV group by mistake.
Means I need to ensure that application is not deploying to production environments accidentally or maliciously from non production stages during a multi stage build process in ADO using Ansible.

Comment: `ansible-inventory -i your/inventory --graph` is a good start. I'll let you explore the rest passing `--help`